# Creating an n array with a linked list of ints

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, trie

I recently made an 26array and tried to simulate a dictionary.

I can't seem to figure out how to make this. I've tried to work with passing in a linkedlist of ints instead of a string. My current code creates 26 nodes(a-z) and then each of those nodes has 26 nodes(a-z). I would like to implement a way to do this with ints, say (1-26). These int nodes will represent items, and the linkedlist of ints I want to pass in will contain a set of ints that I want represented in the tree similar to a string.

Example: pass in the set {1, 6 , 8}, instead of a string such as "hello"

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class N26
{
   private:
       struct N26Node 
        {
          bool isEnd;
          struct N26Node *children[26];
        }*head;

   public:
      N26();
      ~N26();

      void insert(string word);
      bool isExists(string word);
      void printPath(char searchKey);
};
N26::N26()
{
    head = new N26Node();
    head->isEnd = false;
}
N26::~N26()
{
}

void N26::insert(string word)
{
   N26Node *current = head;
   for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
   {
       int letter = (int)word[i] - (int)'a';

       if(current->children[letter] == NULL)
       {
           current->children[letter] = new N26Node();
       }
       current = current->children[letter];
   }
   current->isEnd = true;

}

/*      Pre:  A search key
 *     Post:  True is the search key is found in the tree, otherwise false
 *  Purpose:  To determine if a give data exists in the tree or not
 ******************************************************************************/

bool N26::isExists(string word)
{
    N26Node *current = head;
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(current->children[((int)word[i]-(int)'a')] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        current = current->children[((int)word[i]-(int)'a')];
    }
    return current->isEnd;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand from your description what it is you're trying to do. The question is difficult to answer because the *strong* temptation is to discuss better ways of implementing a solution rather than trying to work with your code here. If you're set on this particular form for the solution, it is better that you keep fuddling with it until you have a specific question about your code.

Comment: http://s14.beta.photobucket.com/user/nousefouraname/media/trie.png.html

Comment: That is an image of the structure im trying to construct.  Basically each node has a counter.  The top most layer of nodes keep track of how many times each single int is present in the data set.  The next layer represents all possible 2Item sets, and the third layer all possible 3 Item sets.  The blue numbers next to the node indicates the counter after the data set has been entered.

Comment: Code in the question leaks all memory it allocates, but that's completely separate from the problem at hand.

Comment: @user1898442: Why are you trying to keep track of the number of times each int is present in the data set?  I can't imagine a use for such a thing, other than [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: @user1898442: The question looks like you want a trie of integers between 1 and 26, instead of characters `'A'` through `'Z'`, is that what you want?  Because that's not even remotely related to the picture and comment you made, which simply counts how many times each node is in use.

Comment: Note that the new posted code won't update the counter, and will report that a word doesn't `Exist` if it's contained in another word (e.g. if you `insert` "book" and "bookworm" -- in either order -- then `isExists("book")` will return `false`). Also `isExists` is painfully ungrammatical.

Comment: What I want to do is data mining.  So if a Transaction is{1,2,6,7}
it will go to layer1-node1 and up that counter(because "1" is in the itemset.  It will then go through layer1-node1 and go to layer2-node2 upping that counter because "1 2" is in the itemset.

Im trying to find out correlations between the Item numbers and how frequently they show up together.  Basically an Apriori algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
class N26
{
  private:
    N26Node newNode(void);
    N26Node *mRootNode;
  ...    
};

N26Node *newNode(void)
{
  N26Node *mRootNode = new N26Node;
  mRootNode = NULL;
  mRootNode->mData = NULL;

  for ( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ )
    mRootNode->mAlphabet[i] = NULL;
  return mRootNode;
}
```

***Ah! My eyes!***

Seriously, you are attempting something much too advanced. Your code is full of bugs and cannot work as intended. Tinkering will not help, you must go back to basics of pointers and linked lists. Study the basics and *do not attempt anything like a linked list of linked lists* until you understand what is wrong with the code above.

I'll give you some hints: "memory leak", "dangling pointer", "type mismatch", "undefined behavior".

Comment: Oh geez wow, I uploaded the wrong file!  Would you mind taking a look again?  perhaps its not AS bad this time.

Comment: @user1898442: It doesn't look as bad. Does it work? How does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite use linked lists, but I managed to get it working using arrays.

```
/* ***  Author:       Jamie Roland
     *  Class:        CSI 281
     *  Institute:    Champlain College
     *  Last Update:  October 31, 2012
     *
     *  Description:
     *      This class is to implement an n26 trie.  The 
     *  operations
     *  available for this impementation are:
     *  
      *  1.  insert
     *  2.  isEmpty
      *  3.  isExists
     *  4.  remove
     *  5.  showInOrder
     *  6.  showPreOrder
     *  7.  showPostOrder
     *
     *  Certification of Authenticity:  
     *     I certify that this assignment is entirely my own work.
     **********************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class N26
{
   private:
       struct N26Node 
        {
          bool isEnd;
          struct N26Node *children[26];
        }*head;

   public:
      N26();
      ~N26();

      void insert(int word[]);
      bool isExists(int word[]);
      void printPath(char searchKey);
};
N26::N26()
{
    head = new N26Node();
    head->isEnd = false;
}
N26::~N26()
{
}

void N26::insert(int word[])
{
    int size = sizeof word/sizeof(int);
   N26Node *current = head;
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       int letter = word[i] - 1;

       if(current->children[letter] == NULL)
       {
           current->children[letter] = new N26Node();
       }
       current = current->children[letter];
   }
   current->isEnd = true;

}

/*      Pre:  A search key
 *     Post:  True is the search key is found in the tree, otherwise false
 *  Purpose:  To determine if a give data exists in the tree or not
 ******************************************************************************/

bool N26::isExists(int word[])
{
    int size = sizeof word/sizeof(int);
    N26Node *current = head;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(current->children[(word[i]-1)] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        current = current->children[(word[i]-1)];
    }
    return current->isEnd;

}
```